Record the called stack of all the thread In a cpp process
I have been developing an unreal engine project. There is an assertion failed from a thread called RHIthread But I don't even know when does thread spawn. Is there any way to see the stack of all the threads with a timeline?    So that at least I could have some idea when does this thread spawn From other thread.


visual studio and intel vtune will do that if you run the application under the profiler, but without debug symbols you won't really know what each thread is doing, you need a debug build of the unreal engine, a better option is to inspect the unreal engine source code looking for it.

fyi what is the RHI Thread?
